# Chrome: Bookmark / Bookmarklet to open a URL with clipboard-Content

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bookmarklet, bookmarks

Is there a way to dynamically include clipboard content into a URL of a Bookmark / Bookmarklet in Chrome?
For example, i copy a story number ("test-1234") and want to open it in jira, it would be helpful i could just click the bookmark, something like this:
[https://jira.mydomain.com/browse/{clipboardContent}](https://jira.mydomain.com/browse/%7BclipboardContent%7D)

and it would open the URL:
https://jira.mydomain.com/browse/test-1234

Or is there a chrome-extension that would make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

With chrome.contexMenu API you can select any text ("test-1234") from any web page
and activate a function (present in the contextual menu)
that opens a new tab (or window) with an URL constructed by the fixed part and the parameter in the queue.
You have to grant "contextMenu" and "activeTab" in your manifest.
For further details please read: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing since years exactly what you've described, but I'm on MacOS and for this I'm using Alfred App (https://www.alfredapp.com). I've created an own Workflow for this. If you're on WIN, then there is something which could be similar to Alfred App --> https://github.com/Wox-launcher/Wox